# Retrieving Subset of a group of data in SQL or SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

My dataset is like the below table.

```
ARR INST DUE_DATE
1   1   1-Dec
1   2   8-Dec
1   3   15-Dec
1   4   22-Dec
2   1   1-Dec
2   2   8-Dec
3   1   5-Dec
3   2   12-Dec
3   3   19-Dec
4   1   6-Nov
4   2   13-Nov
4   3   20-Nov
4   4   27-Nov
4   5   4-Dec
4   6   11-Dec
5   1   1-Jan
5   2   7-Jan
5   3   13-Jan
5   4   20-Jan
5   5   27-Jan
5   6   3-Feb
5   7   10-Feb
5   8   17-Feb
5   9   23-Feb
5   10  24-Feb
```

I need to retrieve data for each arrangements based on the number of installments paid.

Eg. If the total no of installments for a particular arrangement is Less than or equal to 4 then the output should have all the installments values till the 4th installment.

If it is greater than four, or a multiple of four, the the values should be the next subsequent set of four values.

The output should be something like

```
ARR INST DUE_DATE
1   1   1-Dec
1   2   8-Dec
1   3   15-Dec
1   4   22-Dec
2   1   1-Dec
2   2   8-Dec
3   1   5-Dec
3   2   12-Dec
3   3   19-Dec
4   5   4-Dec
4   6   11-Dec
5   9   23-Feb
5   10  24-Feb
```

How to get this output either in SQL server or SAS Enterprise Guide?

Thanks.

Comment: how about if the total is 8 or 12 ?

Comment: I just noticed `multiple of four`.  What is the significance of this, and what happens if the arrangement count is _not_ a multiple of four?

Comment: If it is not a multiple of four, then it should return the subsequent values after the last multiple. 

eg. if there are 15 records, the the INST values of 13, 14, 15 should be displayed since 12 is the last known multiple of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ARR INT, INST INT, DUE_DATE VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1 , 1 , '1-Dec '),
(1 , 2 , '8-Dec '),
(1 , 3 , '15-Dec'),
(1 , 4 , '22-Dec'),
(2 , 1 , '1-Dec '),
(2 , 2 , '8-Dec '),
(3 , 1 , '5-Dec '),
(3 , 2 , '12-Dec'),
(3 , 3 , '19-Dec'),
(4 , 1 , '6-Nov '),
(4 , 2 , '13-Nov'),
(4 , 3 , '20-Nov'),
(4 , 4 , '27-Nov'),
(4 , 5 , '4-Dec '),
(4 , 6 , '11-Dec'),
(5 , 1 , '1-Jan '),
(5 , 2 , '7-Jan '),
(5 , 3 , '13-Jan'),
(5 , 4 , '20-Jan'),
(5 , 5 , '27-Jan'),
(5 , 6 , '3-Feb '),
(5 , 7 , '10-Feb'),
(5 , 8 , '17-Feb'),
(5 , 9 , '23-Feb'),
(5 , 10, '24-Feb'),
(5 , 11, '25-Feb'),
(5 , 12, '26-Feb'),
(6 , 1, '27-Feb')


DECLARE @numofinst INT = 4

SELECT ARR, INST, DUE_DATE FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ARR ORDER BY INST ),
        CNT = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ARR ) 
    FROM @MyTable
) AS T
WHERE 
    RN  > (( CEILING( CAST( CNT AS decimal(18,2) ) / CAST( @numofinst  AS decimal(18,2) )) - 1 ) * @numofinst)
```

Result:

```
ARR         INST        DUE_DATE
----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           1-Dec 
1           2           8-Dec 
1           3           15-Dec
1           4           22-Dec
2           1           1-Dec 
2           2           8-Dec 
3           1           5-Dec 
3           2           12-Dec
3           3           19-Dec
4           5           4-Dec 
4           6           11-Dec
5           9           23-Feb
5           10          24-Feb
5           11          25-Feb
5           12          26-Feb
6           1           27-Feb
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer +1.  I can't delete my answer though until you unaccept it.

Comment: Hi,
This code works, but if the installments is a multiple of 4 then no data is retrieved. 

Eg, If the number of installments is say 12, I need the values from 9 to 12. 

How to implement that condition in the code as well?

Comment: Actually, this code also works for this scenario. I added 10, 11, and 12 rows for ARR 5 and it returns desired result.

Comment: Hi, 
I checked the code for bigger values of installments, Say 124. The records from 96 are listed instead of 121, 122, 123 and 124.

Comment: Are instalments in sequent? I mean, is the count of INST for the ARR  equal 124?

Comment: Yes, For ARR 1 the count of INST is 124. Desired output is INST 121-124 however am getting the values from  97 - 124. Because of the @numofinst+1 I guess.

Comment: You are right, it was not working for big numbers. I made an update. I testes for 124 and it is working now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of sorted SAS data sets, or a remote data source delivering ordered data, the following DATA Step example shows how a double DOW loop can identify and output the rows belonging to the final 4-row chunk of each id:

```
data want(label="Rows from each ids last 4-row chunk");
  do _n_ = 0 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id sequence; %* by sequence not strictly necessary, but enforces the expectation of increasing sequence within id;
  end;

  _out_from_n = floor ( _n_ / 4 ) * 4;

  do _n_ = 0 to _n_;
    set have;
    if _n_ >= _out_from_n then OUTPUT;
  end;

  drop _:;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could modify the code by [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48095723/4965794) to use random read access with the [SET Statement POINT= option](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p0u2yq8x2b1fu4n1m0d5hzam9hjv) as follows:

```
data want;
    retain point 1;
    drop point;
    do _n_ = 0 by 1 until (last.arr);
        set have;
        by arr inst;
    end;
    do point = point+(floor(_n_/4)*4) to point+_n_;
        set have point=point;
        output;
    end;        
run;
```